# Propel-gen fatal error required file not found

Tags: php, propel

I'm new to Propel. A friend of mine had experience with it and recommended it to me but I cannot get it to generate for some reason. I already have a project generated with Propel. I'm trying to generate this project again to check if my installation is correct.

The error I'm encountering is:

> [PHP Error] require_once(/usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/task/../../stubs/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [line 12 of /usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/task/AbstractPropelTask.php]
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/task/../../stubs/functions.php' (include_path='/usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib:/home/casper/Desktop/*/vendor/propel/propel1:/usr/share/php/../classes:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/task/AbstractPropelTask.php on line 12

(folder contains domain of the website, replaced with *)

I suppose the error is it is trying to include:

> /usr/share/php/data/propel_generator/lib/task/../../stubs/functions.php

While it should be trying to include:

> /home/casper/Desktop/*/vendor/propel/propel1/runtime/stubs/functions.php

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Full result of propel-gen: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hzp4caws)
*I am running Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I'd recommend that u use propel2.0. It seems u downloaded/installed an 1.X version with composer. Step on the 2.0 version. [Build proces](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html) for propel2.0 can be found there

Comment: Can you confirm that `pear` and `phing` are correctly installed?